# shoud I declare a new variable, or modify my code?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

The question states:

> You decide to bet on the final match of the Tug of War National
> Championship.
>
> Prior to the match the names and weights of the players are presented,
> alternating by team (team 1 player 1, team 2 player 1, team 1 player
> 2, and so on). There is the same number of players on each side. You
> record the player weights as they are presented and calculate a total
> weight for each team to inform your bet. You write a C program to
> assist with this.
>
> Your program should first read an integer indicating the number of
> members per team. Then, the program should read the player weights
> (integers representing kilograms) alternating by team.
>
> After calculating the total weight of each team, the program should
> display the text "Team X has an advantage" (replacing X with 1 or 2
> depending on which team has a greater total weight).
>
> You will then display the text "Total weight for team 1:" followed by
> the weight of team 1, then "Total weight for team 2:" followed by the
> weight of team 2 (see example below).
>
> You are guaranteed that the two teams will not have the same total
> weight.

I did this on an online compiler and got the right answer

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int nop, i, sum1, sum2;
    int team1_Weight, team2_Weight, player1, player2, answer;
    scanf("%d", &nop);
    for (i=0;i<nop;++i){
        scanf("%d", &player1);
        team1_Weight=team1_Weight+player1;
        scanf("%d", &player2);
        team2_Weight=team2_Weight+player2;
    }
    sum1=team1_Weight;
    sum2=team2_Weight;
    answer=(sum1 > sum2);
    if (answer){
        printf("Team 1 has an advantage\n");
        printf("Total weight for team 1: %d\n", sum1);
        printf("Total weight for team 2: %d", sum2);
    }else{
        printf("Team 2 has an advantage\n");
        printf("Total weight for team 1: %d\n", sum1);
        printf("Total weight for team 2: %d", sum2);
    }
    
}
```

When I submitted this as the answer, I got this:

Compilation error :

```
7066839625989131.c: In function ‘main’:
7066839625989131.c:22:9: error: ‘team2_Weight’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
         printf("Total weight for team 2: %d", sum2);
         ^
7066839625989131.c:21:9: error: ‘team1_Weight’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
         printf("Total weight for team 1: %d\n", sum1);
         ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the team weights?  You have `team1_Weight=team1_Weight+player1;` but that only makes sense if `team1_Weight` already has a known value.  Does it?

Comment: @Lourdh Irudhaya Selvam, the first time `team1_Weight+player1` is executed, what is the value of `team1_Weight`? and why?  What code caused it to have that value?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, you have used `team_weight1` and `team_weight2` before initializing them. The initial values of these variables are indeterminate, which makes the output of your program impossible to determine.

It's possibly the online judge compiler gave these the values you were expecting (likely `0`) but this cannot be counted upon. The solution is simply to explicitly initialize them.